# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff with String resource

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

In my `onCreate` :

```
mLogonUIFacade.init(this, mContext, getString(R.string.XYZ_APP_ID));
```

Logcat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.xyz/com.nw.view.MAFLogonActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2133)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1142)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at com.sap.maf.tools.logon.logonui.LogonView.internalInit(LogonView.java:421)
  at com.sap.maf.tools.logon.logonui.LogonView.<init>(LogonView.java:349)
  at com.sap.maf.tools.logon.logonui.LogonView.<init>(LogonView.java:0)
  at com.sap.maf.tools.logon.logonui.api.LogonUIFacade.init(LogonUIFacade.java:187)
  at com.nw.view.MAFLogonActivity.onCreate(MAFLogonActivity.java:51)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="XYZ_APP_ID">INC.ABC</string>
```

I have looked into other questions of this type, and the problem generally seems to be caused by trying to cast `int` values to `String`, but my resource is a String value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The library you're using is trying to inflate a layout with id `-1` and obviously that does not exist.

Comment: @laalto, this made me head into the right direction; this class was in a different package, and the library was trying to get the application id using this. Thanks (: